# What is the probability of 4 digit numbers formed using the digits 1-6 divisible by 4?

Tags: probability, divisibility

Can anyone please guide me how to approach these kinds of problems with a solution for this problem ?

Comment: Hint: Since 100 is divisible by 4, you only need to check the two last digits (if the last two digits is divisible by 4, then you can write the number as $A*100 + B$ where B is a two-digit number, and $A*100$ is divisible by 4 since 100 is).

Comment: Wow !! That's pretty cool !! So you have 04,08,12,16,24,32,36,44,52,56,64(11) till 100 divisible by 4 formed using 1-6.So till 6666 we have 66*11,which implies probability=(66*11)/(6^4) ?? Please do let me know if i am wrong ?

Comment: @dkuper Sorry 66,i've edited ~!

Comment: Are you allowed to repeat digits?  For example 1166 a valid number?

Comment: @warren Yeah,repetition is allowed !!

Comment: @vaidy_mit and my previous comment still applies: the hint of Greebo means that you really can ignore the two first digits, so there is no reason for "till 6666" or 66

Comment: @Dkuper 726/1296=0.5601. I'm not able to get you,sorry sir ! Can you elaborate ?

Comment: As Greebo says, you just have to compute the probablity that a two-digit number with digits 1-6 is divisible by 4. Update your list because you used $0$, and compute the total number of such two-digits numbers

Comment: So,i have 9 numbers like that after removing 04 and 08.And totally there are 16 numbers between 100 divisible by 4.Therefore,P=9/16 ?

Comment: I agree with the 9 but not with the 16. The denominator should be the numbers of elements of this list (all possible two-digits numbers with your constraint): 11,12,13,14,15,16,21,22,...,66

Comment: @Dkuper Thanks a ton for making me think !! Phew :D Had fun :D Loved this problem :) P=9/36.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10044/discussion-between-vaidy-mit-and-dkuper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

You can ignore the fist two digits and there are only 36 combinations of the last two digits.

List them all and count the ones which are multiples of 4

Comment: @ Warren Thanks !! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your problem, the total amount of possible numbers, before checking whether they are divisible by 4, is $6^4 =1296$.

In order to check divisibility by $4$, we have to take into account that within a number of $4$ digits, the first to digits are not relevant in terms of divisibility: since $100$ is divisible by $4$, we could just analyze what happens with the last two numbers and then multiply by $36$ to account for all the possible combination of the first two digits $\{11,12,13,14,15,16,21, 22, ...\}$.

What happens with the last two digits? Within 20 consecutive numbers, there are $5$ numbers that are divisible by $4$. However, if we remove numbers containing digits $\{7,8,9,0\}$, this number drops to $3$. As we have three "series of 20 censored consecutive numbers", we will have: $3$ ("series") times $3$ (numbers divisible by $4$) $= 9$ numbers divisible by $4$ within each of our $36$ hundreds. So, at the end, the total amount of $4$ digit numbers formed using digits $1$ to $6$ and divisible by $4$ is equal to $9 \times 36 = 324$.

If you want the probability, it will be just $324 / 1296 = 1/4$.